# Resize Soccer Pitch to Fill Screen- React/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I want to resize a soccer pitch that I've drawn in CSS. Basically, the idea is to make the pitch responsive and become a reusable component for web/native development (I will be using React).

Here's my code snippet so far- I'm struggling to figure out how to maximise the CSS `width` so that it takes up most of the available space, whilst still keeping the same dimensions/scale of a soccer pitch (on multiple devices). How should I adjust my `width` and `height` fields?

```css
html {
  --green: #4c7;
  --light: #5d8;
  background: var(--green);
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 60vmin;
  border: 0.5vmin solid white;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, white 1%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 14%, white 0 14.75%, transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 49.75%, white 0 50.25%, transparent 0),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--green) 0 10%, var(--light) 0 20%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS media query aspect-ratio.

Depending on whether the viewport has aspect ratio greater than or less than 9/6 you can set the height of the pitch to the maximum (100vh) and the width as 9/6*100vh and vice versa.

This snippet actually uses 95vh/vw to give you a bit of room round the edge so you can see it's working. Also it defines a class 'pitch' and uses a div as the pitch element rather than body - though of course you are free to use body in the way you have it might be rather constricting if, say, you want to put things round the edge of the pitch.

```css
html {
  --green: #4c7;
  --light: #5d8;
  background: var(--green);
}

.pitch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 95vw;
  height: calc((6 / 9) * 95vw);
  border: 0.5vmin solid white;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 1%, white 0 1.5%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, white 1%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 14%, white 0 14.75%, transparent 0), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 49.75%, white 0 50.25%, transparent 0), repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--green) 0 10%, var(--light) 0 20%);
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/6) {
  /* this means that we have to fit the height to 100vh and the width must adjust accordingly */
  .pitch {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 95vh;
    width: calc((9 / 6) * 95vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pitch"></div>
```